# Autoprefixer error in sublime 4, mapping and package.json

Tags: mapping, sublimetext, package.json, autoprefixer

hi i installed autoprefixer css via package install . node.js is installed and i think i did everything right but when i try running it this error is showing up:

Autoprefixer
Error: (node:20773) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at /Users/"myusername"/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages/Autoprefixer/node_modules/postcss/package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

can someone help me with it ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with one of Autoprefixer's JavaScript dependencies, named [`postcss`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss). The Autoprefixer plugin hasn't been updated in over a year, so some of its dependencies have grown a little stale. However, as detailed [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/sublime-autoprefixer/issues/87), the fix is pretty straightforward.

Open the `Terminal` app, and type in

```
cd "~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text/Packages/Autoprefixer"
```

(don't forget the quotes around the path, as it contains spaces)

Once in that directory, just run

```
npm update
```

and the JS deps should be updated. Restart Sublime, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same error:

> [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in
> the "exports" field module resolution of the package at
> .../node_modules/tslib/package.json.

Then I solved it by exploring in the file /node_modules/tslib/package.json and update the package.json file with the following.

```
"exports": {
    ...,
    "./": "./*"
}
```